# Can't get a Scrollable pre inside bootstrap 3 table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I want a html pre element that is inside a bootstrap table cell to be scrollable.

I have this Code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th class="col-xs-2">Title</th>
            <th class="col-xs-10">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-2">Title</td>
            <td class="col-xs-10">
               <pre style="width:100%; overflow: scroll;"> Very Long Preformated Description </pre>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That actualy expands the pre element outside the screen.

I would like the cell to keep its col-xs-10 size and show scrollable bars on the pre element

Comment: try with max-width and max-height attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this look? 
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/KQOXzK

There's a native Bootstrap 3 class for scrollable tables, you wrap the table as below:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

More info at http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/css/#tables-responsive

====

Here's another version with the scroll bar on the table cell in question, and the entire table stays visible in the viewport:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/pLzWWv

The important bit is that I've wrapped the `<pre>` element in a div with a set width and `overflow-x: auto;`. The full css and HTML is also below.

Good luck!

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-wrap">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th class="col-xs-2">Title</th>
            <th class="col-xs-10">Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-xs-2">Title</td>
            <td class="col-xs-10">
               <div class="pre-wrap">
                 <pre> Very Long Preformated Description Very Long Preformated Description </pre
                 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pre-wrap{
  overflow-x: auto; /* this creates the horizontal scroll bar */
  width:calc(83vw - 10px); /* set the width of this element to the width of col-xs-10 less a little padding */
  background-color:pink;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.table-wrap{
/*   margin optional, to help with illustration only */
  margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi David, Thank you for your answer., I can see that the table gets scrollbars, thats OK. However, its still expands the table outside the screen, I am looking to avoid that. I would prefer the pre element or the cell contaning the pre to be scrollable, and keep the table within the screen borders.

Comment: hey @jos, please check out my alternative suggestion